# How to freeze the first column with `modelsummary`?

Tags: r, modelsummary

Suppose I have an .rmd document that I want to knit into an html with a large number of models:

````r
---
title: "Example Document"
subtitle: ""
output:
  rmarkdown::html_document:
    smart: true
    theme: spacelab
    number_sections: no
    toc: true
    toc_float:
      collapsed: true
    toc_depth: 4
---

```{r echo=FALSE}
library(modelsummary)
library(purrr)
dv <- 
mtcars %>% 
  colnames() %>% 
  .[-1]

models <- 
map(.x = dv,
    ~formula(paste0(.x, "~ mpg"))) %>% 
  map(~lm(.x, data = mtcars))


modelsummary(c(models, models, models))
````

Is it possible to "freeze" the leftmost "variable name" column (or in other words keep it fixed) so that when I scroll to the right, the row names are always visible?

As far as I know, this feature is [not available yet in kableExtra](https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues/585) but it is perhaps [possible using DT](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/extensions.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you okay with using DT?  If so, you can output the `modelsummary()` to data.frame, and pass to `DT::datatable()`, using `extensions="FixedColumns"`:

```
DT::datatable(
  modelsummary(c(models,models,models), output = "data.frame") %>% 
    select(-c(1,3)),
  extensions = "FixedColumns",
  options=list(scrollX = TRUE, fixedColumns = list(leftColumns = 2))
)
```

Comment: This is very cool, thanks for the answer. `DT` looks useful, and I will try to add official support for this package as an output format. Follow this issue if interested: https://github.com/vincentarelbundock/modelsummary/issues/553

Comment: Thank you for adding it as an issue I appreciate it!